# Why is my AVFoundation Speech not working?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, siri

Hey guys this is my code:

```
func configureSpeechButton() {
        contentView.addSubview(speechButton)
        speechButton.setImage(speechImage, for: .normal)
        speechButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(speechButtontapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        //Constraints
        speechButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        speechButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        speechButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        speechButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        speechButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        
    }
    
    @objc func speechButtontapped() {
        
        let speech = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "\(testSpeech)")
        speech.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "de")
        
        let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        synth.speak(speech)
        
    }
    
    let testSpeech = "This is a test"
```

I placed the button on the content view of a scrollView, can someone tell me where's the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure the "de" language code is a valid value?

Answer (score 1):

Your `AVSpeechSynthesizer` is going out of scope. Assign it to a member variable to extend its lifetime.