# AVQueuePlayer not playing Swift

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I am trying to play two sounds in order and when I use `AVQueuePlayer` it will not play any sounds even though when using `AVAudioPlayer` it works fine.

```swift
        let item = AVPlayerItem(url: urlArray[0])
        let item2 = AVPlayerItem(url: urlArray[2])

        let queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: [item, item2])
        queuePlayer.play()
```

I've even tried initializing `AVAssets` with the URL instead and still no luck.

The urlArray is created below:

```swift
let urlOne = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "oneSound", withExtension: "mp3")!
let urlTwo = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "twoSound", withExtension: "mp3")!

urlArray = [urlOne, urlTwo]
```

Comment: could your `AVQueuePlayer` be going out of scope? similar to this situation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65751058/22147

Comment: Yep that was it thank you